# Contents in Div take same amount of space regardless of window size?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently My website looks like this in full screen:

[image]

However when I resize my window, there is a lot of empty space at the bottom like this:

[image]

How do I make it so that the contents take the same amount of space regardless of window size?

```css
#BG1 {
  background: url("../img/IMG_3708.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.BG1C {
  background-color: rgba(103, 128, 159, 0.79);
}
#slide1 {
  height: 600px;
  max-height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 200px 0% 260px 0%;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
}
#NZi2 {
  width: 36%;
  height: 70%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}
#map {
  position: absolute;
}
#Rakiura {
  position: absolute;
  top: 82%;
  left: 64%;
  font-size: 2vw;
}
#Tongariro {
  font-size: 2vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14%;
  left: 86%
}
#Milford {
  font-size: 2vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 58%;
}
#CYR {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 7.5vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6%;
  left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div id="BG1">
  <div class="BG1C">
    <div id="slide1">
      <div id="map">
        <img src="img/NZ6.png" id="NZi2">
        <a href="#slide2" id="Tongariro" title="Sample Text">Tongariro</a>
        <h1 id="Rakiura">Rakiura</h1>
        <h1 id="Milford">Milford</h1>
        <h1 id="CYR">Choose<br> Your<br>Route.<br></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want them to take up the same amount of space without being cut off then your images will become elongated and stretched. The way you have it is fine.

Comment: I was thinking more like the map takes a simillar amount of space in the small window simillar to the amount of space it takes in the big window so there is not a lot of emptyness at the bottom

Comment: You can use media queries which allows you to set the size of divs/images depending on the screen size. So for example you could say that the left side will be 20% width and right size will be 80% width.